# How can I position the elements within 100% height of the device on mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile, touch, viewport

For a hybrid application, i need to build the web part of the application.

I defined that the html and body is 100% of the viewport.
I thought this was a good idea, but it turns out that Android changes the viewport when the touch keyboard is showed. So it resizes all elements on the page. This is not the behaviour that I want.

Is it possible to position and give dimensions on elements based on the device height, without interference from the touch keyboard?

problem shows here http://betapreview.nl/playground/overflow-table/index2.html

**What I did try already**

option 1

`<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True">
    <meta name="MobileOptimized" content="320">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no">`

example: http://betapreview.nl/playground/overflow-table/index2.html

option 2

```
var theHeight = $(document).height();
$("#wrapper").css("height", theHeight);
```

example: http://betapreview.nl/playground/overflow-table/index3.html

Answer (score 1):

You could use jQuery to do this. Just add the following on document ready:

```
var wantedHeight = $(window).height();
var wantedWidth = $(window).width();
```

Then, also in document ready, use wantedHeight and wantedWidth as the values for your wrappers size, like:

```
$('#wrapper').css('height', wantedHeight);
$('#wrapper').css('width', wantedWidth);
```

Comment: Oke good one, but when I applied your JS then i can't see the input.
check it out on http://betapreview.nl/playground/overflow-table/index3.html

Comment: Could you provide me with a screenshot? I dont have access to an android device.

Comment: I will submit a screenshot tomorrow

Comment: screenshot 1: http://betapreview.nl/playground/overflow-table/SC20120815-082922.jpg screenshot 2: http://betapreview.nl/playground/overflow-table/SC20120815-082928.jpg

Watch the border, the blue border div is going wrong when the keyboard pop ups, also the input field is not in sight

Comment: Well, that is expected behaviour when you don't let the document refit  when the keyboard is up. Not much to do I'm afraid. However, I DID believe the Android Browser would focus on the input field selected.

Answer (score 1):

Usually I want pages not to have a page width of 800 to 900 pixels, as the Android and iPhone browsers set it to by default. To have the page width the same as the device width, you may try the following meta tags:

```
<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, user-scalable=no" />
```

BTW you may go through [**Mobile website design for android,iphone**](http://mobile-web-html.blogspot.in/) to take some notes.

Comment: I already have this meta tags, but android browsers make the height smaller when the keyboard shows up

Comment: see http://betapreview.nl/playground/overflow-table/index2.html in android browser (< 3.2 ) to check out the problem